# How to fix blank page after @WebFilter redirect in JSF?

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I'm making an app using JSF and I want to redirect user to login.xhtml from every page (excluding login/register.xhtml) if he's not logged in, using @WebFilter. The problem is that after a redirect all I see is a blank page.

I think it's filtering all resources including bootstrap.css so I used things like this:

```java
if (req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

But it does nothing.

This is my LoginFilter.java

```java
@WebFilter("*")
public class LoginFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Inject
    CurrentSession currentSession;

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String currentPath = req.getContextPath() + req.getServletPath();

        if (!userIsLogged()) {
            if(!currentPath.equals("/app/register.xhtml") && !currentPath.equals("/app/login.xhtml"))
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
        }
        else
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Could someone guide me what should I add to this?

Comment: Solutions belong in answers, not edits of the question. Revert this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should write a custom filter because JavaEE has a buil-in [Security Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm) for Authentication and Authorization.
All you need is could configure in `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.
Here is a minimal project:

```
sample-webapp
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── resources
        │   └── messages.properties
        └── webapp
            ├── pages
            │   ├── admin (restricted for ADMINISTRATORs only)
            │   │   └── admin.xhtml
            │   ├── dashboard.xhtml (available for all logged-in users)
            │   ├── protected.xhtml
            │   └── public (unrestricted pages)
            │       ├── login.xhtml 
            │       └── register.xhtml
            ├── resources (unrestricted public resources)
            │   └── css
            │       └── style.css
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── faces-config.xml
                ├── jboss-web.xml
                └── web.xml
```

All static resource (images, stylesheeets, etc.) is located under `webapp/resources`. The JSF files are located under `webapp/pages/...` but is just an example. The desired behaviour

- Every static resource is public
- login.xhtml and register.xhtml
  (everything under `webapp/pages/public`) are public
- All other pages under `webapp/pages/` are protected and available for all logged-in users
- Pages under `webapp/pages/admin` are available only for ADMINISTRATORS.

In web.xml just configure the following things:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/dashboard.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>stackoverflow-auth-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/pages/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/pages/public/login.xhtml?showerror=true</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Allowed for admin only</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Unrestricted access</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Unrestricted</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/public/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- auth-constraint section is missing which means theese resources are available for everyone -->
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Allowed for all logged in users</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>LoggedIn</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name> <!-- Wildcard role-name means authentication is required but theese resources are available for every roles -->
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In the login.xhtml there are a few requirements.

- The form must submit to `j_security_check` action
- The user and password field must be `j_username` and `j_password` like this:

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>
    <div class="login-box">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{param.showerror}">
        <div class="text-danger">
            <h4>#{msg['login.error']}</h4>
        </div>
    </ui:fragment>
    <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
        <p:inputText id="j_username" placeholder="#{msg['login.username']}"
                     required="true" autocomplete="off"
                     requiredMessage="#{msg['login.error.username']}"/>
        <p:password id="j_password" placeholder="#{msg['login.password']}" required="true" autocomplete="off"
                    requiredMessage="#{msg['login.error.password']}"/>
        <button><h:outputText value="#{msg['login.submit']}"/></button>
    </form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Let's assume you have three differend user types.

- Unauthenticated (who didn`t logged in)
- USER (authenticated)
- ADMINISTRATOR (authenticated and has a special role)

- Unauthenticated user will access `login.xhtml` and `register.xhtml`
  otherwise that user will be redirected to login form.
- Authenticated USER will access all pages under `webapp/pages` except pages under `webapp/pages/admin`. If a USER tries to access an admin page it will
  get a Forbidden response.
- The ADMINISTRATOR user will access every page.

Comment: And what if OP  wants to use filters for other reasons... Than this won't work and the problem might still be there. Any idea what caused the initial problems?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I asked this question, but I thought someone might encounter this post so I'll post my solution here.

```
@WebFilter("*")
public class LoginFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Inject
    CurrentSession currentSession;

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Resources
        boolean isResource = req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER + "/");

        if(isResource)
            chain.doFilter(req, res);

}
```

I used context path and resource identifier to check if the file it's currently loading is a resource.